# c# How to Export a List of Names Alphabetically into a PDF W/Multiple Columns per Page

Tags: c#, t-sql, pdf

I may be overthinking this. I'm letting principals select a list of students from their school and print to a PDF document. I'm retrieving the names from a SQL DB and writing them into an HTMLTable in c#, then passing this table into a PDF convertor. My code below writes the names into a single column table, but there could be over 1,000 names so I want the code to be smart enough to stop after every 30 names and start writing the names into a new column, up to 3 columns per page. This would be easy enough if the list could be alphabetical across the page, but my users want the names alphabetical going down the page.  Below is what I have so far...how can I take this and create new columns if needed?

```
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
HtmlTable tbl = new HtmlTable();
div.Controls.Add(tbl);
tbl.Width = "100%";

HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow();
tbl.Rows.Add(tr);

dl = sp.getDemographicLabels(pageID);

HtmlTableCell tc = new HtmlTableCell();
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
tc.InnerText = "Student Name";

tc = new HtmlTableCell();
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
tc.InnerText = "Enrollment Date";

List<dynaTable> ldt = new List<dynaTable>();
ldt = sp.getActiveStudents_Unformatted(pageID);
foreach (dynaTable dt in ldt)
{
tr = new HtmlTableRow();
tbl.Rows.Add(tr);

foreach (dynaTableColumn dtc in dt.dtc)
{
    tc = new HtmlTableCell();
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc.InnerText = dtc.colValue;
}
}

export dmc = new export();

var sb = new StringBuilder();
div.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)));
string s = sb.ToString();

dmc.exportPDF("Student Profile", "Portrait", s);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int ROWS_PER_PAGE = 30;
            const int COLUMNS_PER_PAGE = 3;

            List<dynaTable> ldt = new List<dynaTable>();

            for(int i = 0; i < 84; i++)
            {
                ldt.Add(new dynaTable() { name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] {(byte)(i + 0x20)})});
            }

            var results = ldt.OrderBy(x => x.name).Select((x, i) => new { person = x, index = i })
                .GroupBy(x => (int)(x.index / (ROWS_PER_PAGE * COLUMNS_PER_PAGE)))
                .Select(x => x.GroupBy(y => y.index % ROWS_PER_PAGE).Select(z => new {
                    col1 = z == null ? string.Empty : z.FirstOrDefault() == null ? string.Empty : z.FirstOrDefault().person.name,
                    col2 = z == null ? string.Empty : z.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault() == null ? string.Empty : z.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().person.name,
                    col3 = z == null ? string.Empty : z.Skip(2).FirstOrDefault() == null ? string.Empty : z.Skip(2).FirstOrDefault().person.name,
                }))
                .SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class dynaTable
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this will work...but I know just enough about Linq to know it when I see it, but not how to use it. I'm trying to iterate through it like this:

foreach (var stud in results)
{
    tr = new HtmlTableRow();
    tbl.Rows.Add(tr);

    tc = new HtmlTableCell();
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc.InnerText = stud.column1;

    tc = new HtmlTableCell();
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc.InnerText = stud.column2;
} but it's highlighting the "new { col1 = z.First..." portion of the linq and saying not set to an object?

Comment: Try hoovering over z and see what z is set to.  Check if it is set to your first row or the middle of your list.  I suspect that issue is when you do not have 90 items per page so columns are empty.  I modified code to test for nulls

Comment: That was it!!  Works perfect now -- thank you very much!!  I was on the right track, I was thinking the same thing and had tried to check for nulls using String.IsNullorEmpty() but I must have been doing something wrong.  Regardless, thanks again for helping an old codger out!!

Comment: I did some more testing and found you can't use Last, instead must be skip(2).  Using last gives duplicates.  See updated code.